# SQL Server - add a column to the result of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that executes like this

```
EXEC @return_value = SP
       @value1 = 'A',
       @value2 = 'B'
```

and the result is:

```
value3 | value 4 | value 5
```

I need to add the columns value1 and value2 to the result (yes, the same I use to execute the stored procedure). There is no chance to change the stored procedure, because it is from another project. Is it possible to do?

I work often with Oracle, so I don't know if maybe it's something simple, or maybe it can't be done.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: *Why* do you want to add two static values? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? This almost sounds like you are trying to do reporting work on the server, eg attaching labels. Or that you used a stored procedure when you really wanted a view or a function

Comment: because one of the values are the date, and i need to know the date for the rest of the values. It's almoust obvious that it must be one of the results from the SP, but since i cannot modify it and in the need to know all the values for a year, i don't want to execute it 365 times.

Answer (score 2):

Store the Proc Results to a temp table.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228165/6167855

Then do something like

```
SELECT @value1, @value2, t.* FROM #TempTable t
```

Comment: I do something similiar, but i forgot to menction that i'm using Sql Server 2000, so i cannot do that (Supported since SQL Server 2008).

Comment: Oh wow @AlanBry. You should really upgraded since 2000 hasn't been supported since April 2013.

Answer (score 0):

With out changing the stored proc ,one way to get desired result is

```
select *,
@value1,
@value2  
from openrowset
('SQLNCLI',
'Server=yourinstancename;
Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC yourproc ''variables''')
```

Note,if you get two result sets,second one will be ignored

Comment: "Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists", it looks good, but...

Comment: @AlanBry:This link seems to provide resolution..https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/03/10/access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-no-login-mapping-exists/